# Cannot convert 'int (*)[(quantityOfEdges + 1)]' to 'int (*)[10000]'

Tags: c++

i am trying a c++ program and i have an error wwhen building function 'solution'.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int checkLevel(int tree[], int range){
// check level of element i (tree[i])
    int rank = 0;
    for (int  i = 0; i <= range; i++)
    {
        rank  += tree[i];
    }
    return rank;
}
int prufer;
void solution (int tree[][10000], int level[], int range){
    int i,j;
    for ( i = 1; level[i] !=1; i++);
    if( i == range +1) return;
    for (int j = 0;  tree[i][j] != 1; j++);
    prufer = j;
    cout << prufer<< " ";
    tree[i][j] = 0;
    tree[j][i] = 0;
    level[i]--;
    level[j]--;
    solution(tree,level,range);
}
int main(){
    int quantityOfEdges;
    
    //create a tree
    cin >> quantityOfEdges;
    int level[quantityOfEdges+1];
    int tree[quantityOfEdges+1][quantityOfEdges+1] ;
    for (int i = 0; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= quantityOfEdges; j++)
        {
           tree[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    {
        int firstElement, secondElement;
        cin >> firstElement ;
        cin >> secondElement;
        tree[firstElement][secondElement] =1;
        tree[secondElement][firstElement] =1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    {
        level[i] = checkLevel(tree[i], quantityOfEdges);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    {
        cout<< level[i]<<" ";
    }
    solution(tree, level, quantityOfEdges;// here
    return 0;
    
}
```

wwhen i run code, i get a following error
error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[10000]'
solution(*tree, level, quantityOfEdges);
^
note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void solution(int (*)[10000], int*, int)'
void solution (int tree[][10000], int level[], int range){
~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: This is what you get for using non-standard features - variable-length array `tree` and `level`. Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: this is not C++:    `int level[quantityOfEdges+1];
    int tree[quantityOfEdges+1][quantityOfEdges+1] ;`  In C a  two-dimensional VLA array can be passed as a pointer to `int` only, so you're passing wrong type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations of arrays using sizes that are variables instead of constants:

```
int tree[quantityOfEdges+1][quantityOfEdges+1];
int tree[quantityOfEdges+1][quantityOfEdges+1];
```

Are not valid C++ except with non-standard compiler extensions like in g++. (Works in C).

The overall fix is to stop working in terms of arrays, but to use std::vector instances instead.

Below is closer to what you want.  Also your variable `j` in `solution` is accessed before it's initialized and is shadowed by the other `j` in that for-loop. So I initialized it to 0.  But you might have a bug there to fix.

I suspect instead of this:

```
for (int j = 0; tree[i][j] != 1; j++);
```

You really meant this:

```
for (j = 0; tree[i][j] != 1; j++);
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int checkLevel(const std::vector<int>& tree, int range) {
    // check level of element i (tree[i])
    int rank = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= range; i++)
    {
        rank += tree[i];
    }
    return rank;
}
int prufer;
void solution(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& tree, std::vector<int>& level, int range) {
    int i, j = 0; // j was originally UNINITIALIZED
    for (i = 1; level[i] != 1; i++);
    if (i == range + 1) return;
    for (j = 0; tree[i][j] != 1; j++);

    prufer = j; 

    cout << prufer << " ";
    tree[i][j] = 0;
    tree[j][i] = 0;
    level[i]--;
    level[j]--;
    solution(tree, level, range);
}
int main() {
    int quantityOfEdges;

    //create a tree
    cin >> quantityOfEdges;

    std::vector<int> level(quantityOfEdges + 1);

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tree;
    tree.resize(quantityOfEdges + 1);
    for (auto& v : tree) {
        v.resize(quantityOfEdges+1);
    }

    // not needed: std::vector will initialize itself to all zeros
    //for (int i = 0; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    //{
    //   for (int j = 0; j <= quantityOfEdges; j++)
    //    {
    //        tree[i][j] = 0;
    //    }
    //}

    for (int i = 1; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    {
        int firstElement, secondElement;
        cin >> firstElement;
        cin >> secondElement;
        tree[firstElement][secondElement] = 1;
        tree[secondElement][firstElement] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    {
        level[i] = checkLevel(tree[i], quantityOfEdges);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= quantityOfEdges; i++)
    {
        cout << level[i] << " ";
    }
    solution(tree, level, quantityOfEdges);// here
    return 0;

}
```